# How can I view test an Angular 2 ErrorHandler override class

Tags: angular, typescript, error-handling, integration-testing

I have successfully overridden the `@angular/core` `ErrorHandler`, however I am trying to create a view test to assert it's behaviour and I'm getting uncaught exceptions. The overriding handler appears not to be running despite working at runtime and setting it in the TestBed providers.

ng2-error-handler.ts:

```
import { ErrorHandler } from '@angular/core';
import { logger } from './logger';

export class Ng2ErrorHandler extends ErrorHandler {

  constructor(){
    super(false); // don't rethrow error
  }

  /* tslint:disable:no-any */
  public handleError(error: any) {
    super.handleError(error);
    logger.handleLoggedError(error, error.message);
  }
  /* tslint:enable:no-any */

}

export const NG2_ERROR_HANDLER_PROVIDER = {
  provide: ErrorHandler,
  useClass: Ng2ErrorHandler,
};
```

ng2-error-handler.view.spec.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NG2_ERROR_HANDLER_PROVIDER } from './ng2-error-handler';
import { TestBed, ComponentFixture } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { logger, Level } from './logger';

const ERROR_MESSAGE = 'Dummy Error';

@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'dummy-component',
  template: `<button (click)="throwError()">Throw an error</button>`
})
export class MockComponent {

  public throwError(): never {
    throw Error(ERROR_MESSAGE);
  }

}

export function main(): void {
  fdescribe('Global Error Handler', () => {

    let fixture: ComponentFixture<MockComponent>;

    beforeEach(() => {
      TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        declarations: [MockComponent],
        providers: [NG2_ERROR_HANDLER_PROVIDER],
      });

      fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MockComponent);
    });

    describe('Error Handler logging', () => {

      let loggerSpy: jasmine.Spy;
      let consoleSpy: jasmine.Spy;
      let errorObservableSpy: jasmine.Spy;

      beforeEach(() => {

        loggerSpy  = spyOn(logger, 'handleLoggedError').and.callThrough();
        consoleSpy = spyOn(console, 'error');

        errorObservableSpy = jasmine.createSpy('log event observable subscription');
        logger.getLogEventObserver().subscribe(errorObservableSpy);

        // trigger the error
        fixture.nativeElement.querySelector('button').click();
      });

      it('should log error to the logger util', () => {
        expect(loggerSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(jasmine.any(Error), ERROR_MESSAGE, Level.ERROR);
      });

      it('should log error to console', () => {
        expect(consoleSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
      });

      it('should have ticked the error stream which will pop error to user', () => {
        expect(errorObservableSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
      });

    });

  });
}
```

All tests fail with

```
Uncaught Error: Error in dist/dev/app/shared/util/ng2-error-handler.spec.js class MockComponent - inline template:0:8 caused by: Dummy Error
  at node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:129
```